# Camera Remote API for DSC-RX1RM2

Tags: api, camera, sony

I am trying to control my Camera DSC-RX1RM2 with Remote SDK.

With the PDF guide [Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API-Reference_v2.20.pdf], 
I think I can use [Continuous shooting mode]API for my Camera,

But the result always return ["error": [12, "No Such Method"]].

I want to ask where is the problem?my camera or the SDK or my source?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the DSC-RX1RM2 is not supported by the API.  Stay tuned to the Sony Camera Remote API page for any updates on supported cameras - https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/.

Comment: Is this still true? I checked this website and it's listed:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/device-support/

Comment: Also even saw a press release for it as well: https://developer.sony.com/2015/10/30/camera-remote-api-beta-sdk-supports-new-features-and-cameras-%CE%B17s-ii-and-rx1r-ii/

Answer (score 0):

The latest API does support the DSC-RX1RM2, just confirmed it.

Also check that your URLs are like:

`http://ip:port/sony/camera`

or

`http://ip:port/sony/avContent`

I didn't append `camera` or `avContent` at first and got similar No Such Method errors.